# flutter theme doesn’t change when hit the switch button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

When I click the switch button the theme doesn’t change like in the tutorial https://youtu.be/6YuQEVN6j-g The full git resp that I follow https://github.com/retroportalstudio/flutter_theming Because when I click the toggle button the theme doesn’t change. So if you guys know plz consider helping. Thanks

My **theme_constants.dart** And **theme_manager.dart** are all the same as tutorial So I don’t think that’s the problems.

My **main.dart** code:

```
ThemeManager themeManager = ThemeManager();

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(create: (_) => AuthBloc(uid: '')),
        Provider(
            create: (_) => GroupModel(
                id: 'id',
                name: 'name',
                leader: 'leader',
                groupCreate: Timestamp.now(),
                members: ['members'])),
        Provider(
            create: (_) => UserModel(
                uid: 'uid',
                email: 'email',
                fullName: 'fullName',
                provider: 'provider',
                groupId: 'groupId',
                groupName: 'groupName',
                groupLeader: 'groupLeader',
                accountCreated: Timestamp.now())),
        Provider(create: (_) => User),
      ],
      //I think the problem is here.⬇️
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Dover Tree',
        theme: lightTheme,
        darkTheme: darkTheme,
        themeMode: themeManager.themeMode,
        home: const LoginScreen(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
```

My theme_screen.dart code:

```
class _ThemeScreenState extends State<ThemeScreen> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    themeManager.removeListener(themeListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    themeManager.addListener(themeListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  themeListener() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    bool isDark = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark; */
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: const Text('Theme'),
        centerTitle: true,
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          Switch(
              value: themeManager.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                themeManager.toggleTheme(newValue);
              })
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your themeManager to providers

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => themeManager)
```